# Retrieving instance of class that was created dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, instance

I have a button on my page so that when I click it another small window pops up letting you enter a Country. This will then appear as a label on my main screen.

This is is the save button.

```
<Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
```

Then I have the code behind.

```
ICommand _AddCountry;
ViewModel _viewmodel;
public NewCountry(ICommand AddCountry, ViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Addcountry = AddCountry;
    _viewmodel = viewModel;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string countryName = txtCountry.Text;

    _viewmodel.RenameCountry(countryName);
    _Addcountry.Execute(null);
    this.Close();
}
```

The label is binded to the Title so that the `Country` will appear as that label.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Country}" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
```

Now this is my problem, when I create that `Country` at runtime, it creates a new instance of the `NewCountryClass` which has a `<String>Country` Property inside BUT also has a `ICollection<string>` Property named `Places`.

```
public class NewCountryClass  : INotifyPropertyChanged

private string _country;

public string Country
{
   get { return _country; }
   set
   {
      if (_country.Equals(value))
         return;

      _country = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Country);
   }
}

private ICollection<string> _places;
public ICollection<string> Places
{
   get
   {
      if (_places == null)
         _places = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      return _places;
   }
   set
   {
      if (value == _places)
         return;

      _places = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Places);
   }
}
```

When I right click on that `Countrys` label on my main screen and click `Add Place` on the drop down, I want that place to get added to that `Country` Instance of that class, inside the `ICollection<string>Places`.

The problem comes when if I create 3 titles on the screen(so it creates 3 different instances of `AddCountryClass`) that when I click `Add place` I cant find the instance of the `Country` I clicked on.

Other useful code in my ViewModel:

```
public void AddCountryCollection()
{
    NewCountryClass newCountryClass = new NewCountyClass(newCountry,"");
    Collections.Add(newCountryClass);
}
```

**This is where I create the instance of the Country, When I enter my Country**

```
public ObservableCollection<NewCountryClass> Collections
{
    get { return collections; }
    set { collections = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => Collections); }
}
```

**This is where the Country gets passed****

```
public void AddPlaces()
{
    NewCountryClass newCountryClass;

    string Item = SelectedCountry.Country;
    Collections.Select(w => w.Country);

}
```

**This was me trying to have a go but It didn't achieve anything**

**Summary**

If I create 3 `Countrys` which use 3 different instances of class `NewContryClass`, When I want to add something into the `ICollection<string>Places` of one of the Countrys, how do I find it?

Comment: in places you have `_counry` and others you have `_country`

Comment: @TI Miss-spelt sorry will change now.

Comment: I am assuming that by title you mean label. So you should create 3 properties for 3 titles. In this way you will have dedicated class per title and it will be much simpler to manage. Not sure if this will solve your problem though. Is the number of titles fixed or is it getting generated dynamically?

Comment: you are using the word ViewModel so is this MVVM? because it doesn't looks like MVVM

Comment: @samar Getting generated dynamically so there could be 7 titles or any amount

Comment: @WiiMaxx I'm new to MVVM, what seems to be wrong?

Comment: your Button should bind with it's `Command` to your VM which handles the ButtonClick [Here an good Tut](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM)

Comment: @WiiMaxx Thanks will take a look, do you know a solution to my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*disclaim i know non view stuff belongs in to the VM but thats the way i do it and i'm fine with it*

### MainV

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Here is how you could select your Country-->

    <Label Content="Country" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Country" Margin="0,0,30,5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CountryCollection}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountryItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="24" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                    Command="{Binding NewCountryCommand}"/>

    <!--Here is how you could show your selected Country-->
    <Label Content="Selected" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedCountryItem}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding Country}"  
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

### MainVM

```
    private RelayCommand _NewCountryCommand; // you can find the RelayCommand Class on the web
    public ICommand NewCountryCommand
    {
        get { return _NewCountryCommand ?? (_NewCountryCommand= new RelayCommand(param => this.OnNewCountry())); }
    }
    public void OnNewCountry()
    {
         var window = new Window(); // or whatever View you use
         var vm = new NewCountryClass();

         window.DataContext= vm;
         window.ShowDialog();

         if(vm.Result)// Result will be set to true 
                      // if the user Click the Save Button in your CountryV
         {
              // here will be your logic if the user want to save his stuff
              // in my case
              CountryCollection.Add(vm)
              SelectedCountryItem = vm;
         }
    }


public ObservableCollection<NewCountryClass> CountryCollection
{
    get { return collections; }
    set { collections = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged(() => CountryCollection); }
}

public NewCountryClass SelectedCountryItem
{
    get { return selectedCountryItem; //}
    set { selectedCountryItem = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCountryItem); }
}
```

and thats it.

You can also take a look at [this Tut](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple) which provided some [Samplecode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMMadeSimple/SIMPLE_MVVM_SOURCE.zip)

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer! 2 Questions firstly, As you can see my constructor for my `NewCountryClass` takes in Country and Places? So when I create an instance of it in my `ViewModel`, do I need to pass anything? Or should I not have this in my constructor? Also `if(vm.Result)` Does not contain a definition for `Result`.

Comment: @Ben Result is a Property you need to add in my case it is a Boolean. Your constructor could have an overload which doesn't need a Country object and no Places (so do i figure out if it is a new Object which i need to save or an Object which just get edited be the user and i only need to update it)

Comment: Well I need it be update if the user wants to change the Country, but also the user can save the form to a file so they can load it back up.

Comment: @Ben i just answer your question _When I want to add something into the ICollection<string>Places of one of the Countrys, how do I find it?_ Now it's your part to create some save and update logic. if you are not able to do this please ask another Question

Comment: Oh that comment I made wasn't I question, When you last said your comment the part in the brackets I thought was asking me something my bad -.- I know how to save things to file etc ...